# Keep minimized windows minimized when restarting an app (Firefox)

Tags: gnome, firefox, window, minimize

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and I usually have multiple Firefox windows open, some of which I keep minimized for later use. When I close Firefox and start it again, those minimized windows are restored, which differs from window behavior on both Windows and OS X, which keep minimized windows minimized when you restart your application. This behavior is not specific to Firefox, it happens with all applications. Can this behavior be altered on Ubuntu? I would really like for apps to remember which windows should be minimized and which should not be.

Answer (score 0):

Strange but a few days later windows stay minimized after a restart so basically it's now working exaxtly as I wanted without me changing anything.